# How can I get mysql result as a array

Tags: mysql, arrays, translate

Here I have a translator that must get data from mysql and then show them like a $_name = array ($_en, $_ru, $_ua) and then I want to choose data by cases [0] or [1] or [3]

I need to show mysql result an array

I've already try this it but it doesn't work

```
<?php

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT t_name, t_ru, t_ua, t_en FROM transl_db ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

t_name = array ('t_ru', 't_ua', 't_en' )

}

?>
```

Comment: `$t_name = array ($row['t_ru'], $row['t_ua'], $row['t_en'] );`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT t_name, t_ru, t_ua, t_en FROM transl_db ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
     $t_names[] = array ('t_ru'=>$row['t_ru'],'t_ua'=> $row['t_ua'],'t_en'=>$row['t_en'] );
}
```

or

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
     $t_names[] = $row;
}
```

now data available on  `$t_names`

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysql_query("SELECT t_name, t_ru, t_ua, t_en FROM transl_db ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
     $t_names[] = $row;

Answer (score 0):

I tried it but I have to get also $t_name from mysql and then have it like an array

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT t_name, t_ru, t_ua, t_en FROM transl_db ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
('t_name'=>$row['t_name'] )= array ('t_ru'=>$row['t_ru'],'t_ua'=> 
$row['t_ua'],'t_en'=>$row['t_en'] );
};

?>
```